# Remotely launch files that are not part of current workspace?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm aware of the  tag which is used to launch remote nodes. However, this seems to fail when the remote node workspace is different from the local workspace.

Specifically, if I have a package "remote_pkg" in my remote workspace, but not in my local workspace (where I am calling it from), I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: remote_pkg
```

My launch file is as follows:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="remote_machine" address="remote_machine.local" user="ubuntu"/>
    <include machine="remote_machine" file="$(find remote_pkg)/launch/main_online.launch"/>
</launch>
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230688/remotely-launch-files-that-are-not-part-of-current-workspace?/) by [sr71](https://answers.ros.org/users/25009/sr71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bit of a footnote, but the [docs for roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) do clearly state:

> Substitution args are currently resolved on the local machine. In other words, environment variables and ROS package paths will be set to their values in your current environment, even for remotely launched processes.

This includes the `$(find pkg)` substitution.

This means that any launch files that you want to launch remotely need to exist on the local machine, and they need to be at the same absolute path on both the local and remote machines.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sr71](https://answers.ros.org/users/25009/sr71/) on 2016-03-31**:
I see. For now, I will pass in an absolute path. Thank you.